# How to Change Owner of a Directory

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown

**EDIT**: The problem was that Apple uses permissions to mark *backups* and prevents you from modifying them (probably a security feature). By using `chmod -RN <dir>` I removed ACL data from all the folders with important data and that allowed me to make myself the owner and apply the appropriate permissions.

*Original question*
I have an extremely large backup (>700GB) that now has the wrong permissions (my UID changed during clean install, long story) and I need to change them. The time-consuming option is to manually go through each folder and change the permissions but that will take ages.

I want to use `chown` to make myself the owner of all my important data and then use `chmod 700` on all those folders to give `rwx` permissions to only me.

The ideal solution is some method of using `find` to recursively look for folders matching a regex (my current one is `.*/[DCV].*|Pictures|M[ou].*`) and then make my UID the owner and set the permissions to 700.

**The important bit that I can't grasp:**
However, when I try to run `chown Me DirectoryName` I get `chown: DirectoryName: Operation not permitted`.

Everything I find is related to changing the permissions of a *file* and not a directory. Maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way?
Something tells me there isn't a way of giving my UID `rwx` and `---` to everyone else.

How can I achieve this? I'm running Mac OS X 10.10.3.

I know that this is a UNIX/Linux forum (and I'm running Mac) but this question is a lot more about using the shell, `chown`, `chmod`, and permissions and any solutions posted here will be applicable to any UNIX-based OS. It would be preferable if the posted solutions will make my older backups reappear in Time Machine.

<strike>Thanks to all who have promptly replied, but `chown` just doesn't seem to work on directories for some reason. Is the fact that this is a `.sparsebundle` disk image on a network drive relevant? I assumed it would be the same as on any external drive.</strike>

Comment: What kind of network drive?  If it's NFS, there's a good chance it's exported with `root_squash` enabled, so you won't be able to perform root-only operations such as `chown` from the client.

Comment: It's a HDD inside an Apple Time Capsule. Essentially it's a password-protected disk inside a WiFi base station. The only difference is that the HDD is connected to your computer via ethernet. There actually _is_ a USB port but I've never used it.

Comment: Otherwise, the standard `find . -user $other_uid -print0 | sudo xargs chown $USER` should work.

Comment: What network filesystem?  `df -hT <dirname>` should tell you.

Comment: @TobySpeight `df -hT <dir>` gives _no output_ for a) the root directory of the network HDD b) the disk image inside the network HDD c) any folder on the network HDD. Perhaps the behavior you intended is implemented differently on Mac and on Linux?

Comment: Weird - I expected a `Type` column with appropriate filesystem type (e.g. I get `ext4` for `df -hT /` here).  Does `df` work at all on your system?  I only know Linux for this, so speculating a bit...

Comment: On Mac `df -T <type>` means you want to list info only for a certain type on filesystem (not sure how to use). A Mac version of the behavior you describe is `diskutil list`. The format or "type" for the disk image with my backups is "Apple_HFS".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I may have misunderstood. But you can recursively use chmod and chown eg.

```
chown -R username:username /path/directory
```

To recursively apply permission 700 you can use:

```
chmod -r 700 /path/directory
```

Of course the above is for Linux so not sure if mac osx is the same.

EDIT: Yea sorry forgot to mention you need to be root to chown something, I just assumed u knew this...my bad.

Comment: Mac OS uses the same syntax. To execute the command as root, the easiest way on a Mac is to prefix it with `sudo`, so `sudo chmod` (you will be asked for a password with Adminstrator access).

Answer (score 2):

try *as root*

```
 find wherever -type d -name ... -exec chown Me {} \;
```

where

- `-type d` apply to dir only
- `-name ...` your regexp
- `-exec chown Me {} \;` use chown on find dir.

you must be root to chown.